# Time complexity of $a^{n^b}; a,b>1$

Tags: time-complexity

What ist the time complexitiy of an algorithm with the running time of $a^{n^b}; a,b>1$? And how is it compared to factorial complexity O(n!)?

Comment: What do you mean by the running time of an expression?  You can compute the running time of an algorithm, but not an expression.  What are your thoughts?  Please [edit] the question to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider $n!<e\left( \frac{n}{2} \right)^n=e^{n\ln n+1-n\ln2}$. On other hand $a^{n^b}=e^{n^b \ln a}$. Now we should compare $(n\ln n+1-n\ln2)$ to $n^b \ln a$, where right member wins, when $a,b>1$:
$$\frac{n\ln n+1-n\ln2}{n^b \ln a}\to 0$$